# Import files exists to project eclipse C++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, build

I am using eclipse to dev my application for linux. I have my library source  in workspace/mylib/ and the project in workspace/project.
In a source of my project i include the relative path of source library file, 
example: #include "../mylib/foo.h" 
The problem start when i try build it, in all parts that use library source eclipse shows this error: undefined reference to 'function()'

I think that it is by library files  don't have in src folder or not link.

Any Idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, u r right man! It's definitely by library files don't have in src folder or not link.

Answer (score 0):

```
error: undefined reference to 'function()'
```

Indicates that the linker cannot find the definition of the `function()`. Either you have not defined it in your source code Or If you are using a library which defines it, the library is not getting linked.

[This](http://whatwouldnickdo.com/wordpress/328/eclipse-cdt-and-linux-libraries/) or [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_add_an_external_library_to_my_C.2B.2B_project.3F) posts explain what you should do to add external libraries to eclipse.

Comment: I have included the in the source file #include "../mylib/libfile.h" in the same file when function is called.

Comment: @kar: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to say, But if you are trying to say you already have the function definition in source code you wrote and are still getting the linking error then Please post your source code.

Comment: I have included the myfoo.h file in foo.cpp file, this file foo.cpp calls to function that is defined into myfoo.h file.